# Copy large amount of commits to new branch

Tags: git

I have three branches:

- releaseX
- develop
- topicA

**releaseX** was branched from **develop** maybe two weeks ago.

**topicA** was branched from **develop** a long time ago. Because we knew it was going to get merged into a release branch eventually, we kept merging **develop** into it. Unfortunately, we now have a good amount of commits in **develop** that we don't want in our **releaseX** branch.

Here's a diagram of my scenario:

```
      (releaseX)
     /
A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H (develop)
                     \
                      S---T---X---Y (topicA)
```

Above, I need to keep commits like `S` `T` `X` `Y`, but need to get rid of `C` and `E`. The number of commits in question is about 50 or more, but clearly I couldn't illustrate them here.

My goal is to create a branch based off of **releaseX** with 50+ relevant commits from **topicA**. I've tried creating a new branch off **releaseX** and then rebasing the new branch on **topicA**, but this didn't allow me to exclude the commits I didn't want in there.

*What is the best way to "cherry pick" these 50+ commits into a new branch (**topicA_clean**) based off **releaseX**?*

Comment: rebase onto sounds like a possible candidate here.  Can you show us a diagram which explains what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Is the number of commits to cherry-pick an estimate or do you know exactly how many commits there are? Do you have a list of commits? This would make cherry-pick pretty easy I assume.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - added

Comment: @AnimiVulpis - The number of commits is an estimate (but it is in this range) and I do have a list of these commits. I just want to avoid the very tedious task of cherry-picking 50 individual commits (merge conflicts and all).

Comment: If you need to remove sporadic commits from the history, then an interactive rebase is one option.  Just delete those commits you don't want and complete the rebase.

Comment: If you already have the list of commits I don't see why a `cherry-pick` would be tedious? (Other than possible conflicts which are inevitable).

Comment: @AnimiVulpis A cherry pick (or several of them) might be error prone.  Anyway, it seems easier to just squash down to what the OP wants.

Comment: Git 1.7.2 or later can cherry pick a range of commits. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.2.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a solution that uses `git cherry-pick` (works with `git --version` >= 1.7.2):

It is possible to `cherry-pick` a list of commits with ease:

```
$ git cherry-pick -x <commit-hash-1> <commit-hash-2> <...> <commit-hash-X>
```

*I like to use the `-x` option to be able to find the original commits later on*

---

If you happen to have a list of the commits you want to `cherry-pick` you can use a tiny bit of command line magic like so:

```
$ cat cherry-pick-hashes.md | xargs git cherry-pick -x
```

Comment: Nice `xargs` option with cherry-pick +1 ... I'd rather use that than list them out in the actual command.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could list commit hashes in `cherry-pick`. Approved. Thanks!

Comment: Could someone, for the sake of completeness, suggest an alternative to `xargs` for other environments like windows?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if there are more commits to take or to drop.

If you have more commits to take then you could create a new branch based on topicA and with `git rebase --interactive HEAD~50` delete the commits that you don't want to keep.

If you have more commits to drop than to take you can cherrypick the commits that you want.

Comment: I just want to add that you could use the `--onto`to be able to specify from which commit start the picking and easily filter a lot of commits at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Given the number of commits required, a good solution is to use `git rebase --onto`.

Illustratively, your situation looks like the following after merging develop back into topicA with four commits highlighted, E, F, G and H:

```
                              o---o---o releaseX
                             /
o---o---o---E---o---F---H---o---o develop
         \       \       \
          o-------o---G---o topicA
```

Now let's suppose the commits you want are E, F, G and H. Here is a diagram of what that would look like:

```
                              o---o---o---E'---F'---G'---H' releaseX
                             /
o---o---o---E---o---F---H---o---o develop
         \       \       \
          o-------o---G---o topicA
```

First we want E, `git rebase --onto releaseX E~1 E` and now releaseX now points to E'.

To get F and H, `git rebase --onto releaseX F~1 H` and now releaseX points to H'.

Finally, `git rebase --onto releaseX G~1 G` completes the task.

Comment: ..and use `git rebase -i / --interactive` to **review the plan** and see what commits are in the scope of action before anything changes. This saves time, makes learning rebase easier, works with `--onto`, and is 100% safe unless you are rebasing across merges.

Comment: ..and do a `git branch tmp-backup` before executing rebase, to mark your current branch with a new `tmp-backup` branch name. Thanks to that, if rebase goes not like you want, you can easily have your rebased branch back to the previous that exact spot.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to rebase **topicA** on commit **B**? If this succeeds then it will propably posible to merge topicA_rebased to **releaseX** and **develop** as they all three would have the common ancestor **B**.